# How to remove arrow icon on accordion panel headers using PrimeNG?

Tags: css, angular, image, typescript, primeng

I just want to remove arrow icons from accordion panel headers using [**PrimeNG**](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/accordion). Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

**Code:**

```
<p-accordion>
  <p-accordionTab header="Godfather I">
   Content 1
 </p-accordionTab>
 <p-accordionTab header="Godfather II">
    Content 2
 </p-accordionTab>
 <p-accordionTab header="Godfather III">
    Content 3    
 </p-accordionTab>
```

Here's an image:
[image]

Comment: Source code has those hard-coded so you can either submit a pull request or modify the source code to work in your case.

EDIT: I submitted a PR for customizable icons but haven't been merged yet.

Comment: @ChauTran would you suggest a simple way to remove those icons? thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give your `p-accordion` a `styleClass="someStyleClass"` then go to your root `styles` and add these:

```
.someStyleClass.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header span.fa {
  display: none;
}
```

or if you use `SCSS`

```
.someStyleClass.ui-accordion {
  .ui-accordion-header {
    span.fa {
      display: none;
    }
  }
}
```

EDIT: This is the simplest solution that I personally can think of that is not messing with the source code.

Answer (score 5):

There's a property in PrimeNG, that allows us to manipulate the icons for accordion.

`expandIcon` and `collapseIcon`: to be used on `<p-accordion>` tag.

We may use something like `<p-accordion expandIcon = "" collapseIcon= "">` and this should work like a charm.

Similarly, this could be used when we want to change the icons, as per our needs, say "+" or "-".

```
<p-accordion expandIcon = "pi pi-plus" collapseIcon = "pi pi-minus">
```

More info on https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/accordion

Peace